# List of Registered Taxonomies of Current Post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get list of registred taxonomies of current post,
I mean:

```
register_taxonomy('color',array('thing'),$args) ;
register_taxonomy('shape',array('thing'),$args) ;
register_taxonomy('material',array('thing'),$args) ;
// etc..
```

So how can I get the list of taxonomies that registred to 'thing' posttype?
Must be something like:

```
$taxonomies = get_registred_taxonomies_of('thing') ;
print_r($taxonomies) // Show "color,shape,material"...
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [**`get_object_taxonomies`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) ex:

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('thing') ;
print_r($taxonomies) // Show "color,shape,material"..
```